# Aggregate function does not respect alphabetical order of a vector

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data.frame that (simplified) looks like this:

```
Binomial<-c(rep("Capra aegagrus",2),rep("Capreolus capreolus",3),"Capra ibex")
area<-c(500,200,10,300,15,5)
mydata<-data.frame(Binomial,area)
```

I want to obtain a new data.frame with the names of the species (`mydata$Binomial`) and the sum of all the areas of each species. This is my process so far:

```
#sum all the areas of each species 
a<-aggregate(mydata$area,list(mydata$Binomial),FUN=sum)
#create a vector with a length equal to mydata number of rows
n<-max(lengths(mydata)) 
#insert the total of the areas of each species in the first row, and fill the rest with NA 
b<-lapply(a, `length<-`, n) 
summary(b)  
#Group.1 is the species, x is the area
#create a column with the species 
mydata$Binomial_2<-b$Group.1 
#create a column with the areas
mydata$area_tot<-b$x 
#create a final data frame with the species and the total of the areas 
mydata_2<-mydata[c(1:3),c(3:4)]
```

So far it worked on different datasets. The problem is that if I check `a`, I see that species are not in the same order as they were in `mydata`: now Capra ibex is before Capreolus capreolus. This messes up my following analyses. Do you have a suggestion on how to preserve the alphabetical order of `mydata` in this script? This means it should be Capra aegagrus, then Capreolus capreolus, and lastly Capra ibex in `mydata_2` as well. Thanks.

Comment: The alphabetical order was preserved, the problem is that `Capra` with an **a** comes before `Capreo` with an **e**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the subject of the question, as a commenter already pointed out, the output is in alphabetical order so we assume that that is not the problem and that the problem is that we want the input order to be preserved.

**1) factor**  Define the `Binomial_2` column to be a factor with the desired order. That is, after defining `mydata` in the first chunk in the question replace the rest of the code with:

```
tmp <- transform(mydata, Binomial_2 = factor(Binomial, levels = unique(Binomial)))
aggregate(area ~ Binomial_2, tmp, FUN = sum)
##                Binomial_2 area
##     1      Capra aegagrus  700
##     2 Capreolus capreolus  325
##     3          Capra ibex    5
```

or using pipes:

```
mydata |>
  transform(Binomial_2 = factor(Binomial, levels = unique(Binomial))) |>
  stats:::aggregate.formula(formula = area ~ Binomial_2, FUN = sum)
```

**2) ave** Another approach is:

```
tmp <- with(mydata, 
  data.frame(Binomial_2 = Binomial, area = ave(area, Binomial, FUN = sum)))
unique(tmp)
##            Binomial_2 area
## 1      Capra aegagrus  700
## 2 Capreolus capreolus  325
## 3          Capra ibex    5
```

with pipes this could be expressed as

```
mydata |>
  with(data.frame(Binomial_2 = Binomial, area = ave(area, Binomial, FUN = sum))) |>
  unique()
```

Comment: This works and also gives a nicer result - although I stuck with `aggregate(area ~ Binomial, mydata, FUN = sum)`. I didn't understand why you do add `cbind(Binomial_2 = Binomial)`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The cbind changes the column name to be the same as the question.  I have simplified the code a bit so we don't need that any more..